# Copy excel files with specific in a folder into master worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

For one  of my project I need to Copy data from multiple excel workbook in a folder to a master worksheet.

Earlier the requirement was to just copy the sheet1 from all the files but with the new change I need to 
copy both sheet 1 and sheet 4 from all the files.

Headers on all the worksheet is same

I have tried various code to make changes in the current code but unable to drive any result.

Therefore wanted to check with the experts here if you have came across with such issue and can suggest possible suggestion regarding the same.

Thank you very much for your time and efforts in advance.

```
*Sub FILESMERGE()
Dim wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, fPath As String, fName As String
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
fPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\FTC" 'Provide folder path here
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then fPath = fPath & "\" 'Make sure separator is on end of path
fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xlsx*") 'get all Excel files in directory
    Do
        If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)
            With wb.Sheets(1)
                If Application.CountA(.Rows(2)) > 0 Then
                    .UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)

                End If
            End With
            wb.Close False
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop While fName <> ""



End Sub*
```

Comment: You are working with `wb.Sheets(1)` already - well you need to work with `wb.Sheets(4)` too then.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the suggestion it did work but  using the codes again will reopen  all the files again , wondering if you have any suggestions for copy the data from Sheet 4 right after pasting the data from Sheet 1